# Which Barcode / QR code scanner plugin should be used to work with Blackberry Access in Android Mobile?

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-dynamics

I am working on Ember Application. Have checked the following plugins for barcode\ qr code scanning. But none of then works in Blackberry Access browser on Android phone.

**Plugins Checked**

- Instascan
- html5-qrcode
- Quagga2
- Zxing-js
- jsqrcode
- qr-scanner
- webcodecamjs
- Ember-scanner
- Scandit

Please help me with any plugins or any other way we can get scanner working on Blackberry Access.

Comment: Are these all failing with a similar error you mentioned for ZXing-js of "DOM Exception: Permission Denied"? Or is there different behaviours you are seeing? I'm looking into this and will follow up next week with what I find out.

Comment: Yes.. for all the plugins I am getting Permission Denied error. Thanks for your help..

Comment: I found out that BlackBerry Access for Android does not allow JavaScript access to the camera or microphone and unlike other platforms does not have an option to enable it. Internally at BlackBerry I've suggested this be supported. It's being tracked with internal ID FER-14176. You can reference that ID in the future with a BlackBerry employee (I am one of those) to ask for a status update.